# how to define path in SMB

Tags: java, smb

I have a scenario where I need to send a file from my machine to some shared location. When I can see shared location on my machine (windows 7) is shown as N: drive.

the O/P for `net use` command to find its remote and I get it as `\\smb\ds`

I'm writing code to write the string to file in remote location i.e. `N:\TESTING_GOING_ON\test.txt` it goes like this,

```
String user = "abcd:XXXXX";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
String path = "smb//ds/TESTING_GOING_ON/test.txt";
SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
try (SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile)) {
    sfos.write(str.getBytes());
    sfos.close();
}
```

using `jcifs.smb.*`
But, for path I'm getting either no protocol defined or failed to connect.

So someone could please let me know the path I'm using is correct or not.
If incorrect what how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html) seems pretty clear (though I haven't tested).  The example format is

```
smb://storage15/public/foo.txt
```

so for you, that should be

```
smb://smb/ds/TESTING_GOING_ON/test.txt
```

Assuming your SMB server is actually named `smb`, which would be, interesting.

Comment: but would this be same path for linux environment too. I'm trying to run the same program on cloud its failing for connection. In the document it has not given that is it windows specific or linux

Comment: Yes, it's the same everywhere.  I would suspect firewall issues.  Try running on Linux locally to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that and post the result here. But when it comes to transfer a file from one to another place what all are the connection methods like using FTP and  etc.  any suggestion of reading any document.

Comment: May be this the above one would be a wrong question but I'm looking for how does it transferring the file and what ports do I need to provide to network dept. when it comes to open the firewalls settings or connect to internal drive from cloud

Comment: Hello, sounds like you have two brand new questions, as there are dozens of ways to transfer files.  That said, https://serverfault.com/questions/346196/tcp-ip-ports-necessary-for-cifs-smb-operation will be useful for one of them.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I just saw the link provided and received pretty much good idea about the question I was looking for. not completely though.